# Объясните что делает процедура отображения шрифта

Tags: c++, шрифты, arduino

Пытаюсь создать шрифт для arduino проекта. А библиотека дисплея содержит код, который я понимаю что делает, но не понимаю как. Из-за этого участка не получается добавить русский шрифт.

```
void Paint::DrawCharAt(int x, int y, char ascii_char, sFONT* font, int colored) {
    int i, j;
    //Height=16, Width=11
    unsigned int char_offset = (ascii_char - ' ') * font->Height * (font->Width / 8 + (font->Width % 8 ? 1 : 0));
    const unsigned char* ptr = &font->table[char_offset];

    for (j = 0; j < font->Height; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < font->Width; i++) {
            if (pgm_read_byte(ptr) & (0x80 >> (i % 8))) {
                DrawPixel(x + i, y + j, colored);//рисуем пиксель
            }
            if (i % 8 == 7) {
                ptr++;
            }
        }
        if (font->Width % 8 != 0) {
            ptr++;
        }
    }
}

const uint8_t Font16_Table[] PROGMEM = 
{
    // @0 ' ' (11 pixels wide)
    0x00, 0x00, //            
    0x00, 0x00, //            
    0x00, 0x00, //    xxx
};

sFONT Font16 = {
    Font16_Table,
    11, /* Width */
    16, /* Height */
};
```

Код выше берет и пробегается по таблице `Font16_Table`, где указаны через запятую HEX коды. С этим вроде понятно, но добавив в эту таблицу свой шрифт - он не отображается. В данном случае 32-ва HEX кода образуют 1 букву. Т.е. процедура получает чар код буквы и каким-то образом понимает положение её HEX кода.

Объясните, как надо сделать пропуск чар кода, если ставить 0, 0, и т.д. не помогает? И в целом что делает та процедура?

Вот процедура которая вызывает его:

```
void Paint::DrawStringAt(int x, int y, const char* text, sFONT* font, int colored) {
    const char* p_text = text;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    int refcolumn = x;

    /* Send the string character by character on EPD */
    while (*p_text != 0) {
        /* Display one character on EPD */
        DrawCharAt(refcolumn, y, *p_text, font, colored);
        /* Decrement the column position by 16 */
        refcolumn += font->Width;
        /* Point on the next character */
        p_text++;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что она берет текст, получает посимвольно char код буквы, затем этот код является числом допустим русская буква А будет иметь код 192. Все равно не могу понять как же указывает код на таблицу HEX где ей искать начало русской буквы А. Если просто добавить в конец HEX буквы А - получаю иероглифы или еще что но только не мою нарисованную букву. С правильностью формирования буквы я разобрался - 100% уверен что букву рисую правильно. Пробовал заменил английскую букву например H и нарисовал вместо нее нашу русскую У. При вводе текста H выводится У - все ок. Но кириллицу невидет как буд-то. Помогите разобраться, от ответа частично стало понятнее, но не совсем :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned int char_offset = (ascii_char - ' ') * font->Height * (font->Width / 8 + (font->Width % 8 ? 1 : 0));`

Смещение в таблице: `(ascii_char - ' ')` - номер символа относительно пробела (0x20)

`(font->Width / 8 + (font->Width % 8 ? 1 : 0))`  в данном случае (ширина 11) отводится 2 байта на горизонтальный скан символа

`char* ptr = &font->table[char_offset];` указывает на начало линии символа

`(pgm_read_byte(ptr) & (0x80 >> (i % 8)))` выделяется i-й бит, считая со старшего (MSB), и если он единичный, то рисуется на экране

`if (i % 8 == 7) { ptr++;` переход ко второму байту скан-линии символа

таким образом, например, последовательность `0x80,0x20`, повторённая 16 раз, должна вывести две вертикальные линии по краям символа

**Edit:**

> русская буква А будет иметь код 192

Если тут **не напутано с кодировками**, то описание символа с номером 192 должно быть в таблице с индексом 192-32=160 (или смещение в байтах от начала 320)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, данный код выше вызывается следующим кодом (наверное имел смысл его сразу предоставить, не подумал):

Comment: Код в комментариях не читается, я перекинул в вопрос, но по применению-то всё должно быть понятно

Comment: т.е. чтобы он увидел русскую букву А надо к таблице добавить к текущему кол-ву индексов столько индексов чтобы получилось на 160 индексе мое начало кириллицы верно?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы char_offset стал 160 (и при этом убедиться, что A действительно 192)

Comment: Можно ли заполнить пустые ничего не значащие индексы нулями? 0, 0, 0, 0 и т.д.?

Comment: Да, конечно. Но вообще, если стоит задача экономить память под таблицу, можно её упаковать, так что сразу после нужных символов латинских идут кириллические (с соответствующим пересчётом offset)